# how to set id for each item in ListView

Tags: java, android

When I retrieve data from database, I  have for each row unique ID I want match id with string in listview but ID I want it to be invisible, so that  when i click any item in listview trans me to another activity have data about this item.

That means I have Two table in database match together I  want to retrieve one as listview , when click item trans me to data match the item i have been clicked.one as listview , when click item trans me to data match the item i have been clicked.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
myAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());

public class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder {
@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String text){
    //Since it iterates through all the views of the item, change accordingly 
    if(view instanceof TextView){ 
        ((TextView)view).setTag("whatever you want");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: UpVote to your answer Mr.Conor :

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom adapter and use like this method to achive yor goal

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if(vi == null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    }

    final int id = idGetFuncttion(position);

    vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doSomethingWithID(id);              
        }
    });

    return vi;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.set your unique id to each row by setTag property and retrieve it by getTag property
2.use custom adapter and custom listview layout for the listview and set your unique id to invisible textview in custom listview layout through custom adapter
```