# Setting Unique Id to ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which shows person  information from database. Is that possible to add a particular ID like personid to each item in listview, so that I can use that ID to be passed to another page on clicking the list view item .  I am using a SimpleAdapter for the ListView.
I have seen a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960901/how-to-set-id-for-each-item-in-listview) .But that doesn't fully satisfies my requirement.
Is there a way to directly set the Id , like what we do in the List of  hashmaps  for setting in  SimpleAdapter

Comment: When you click on the item you get its position, won't it work for you?. If not you can set tag using `setTag()` method on the listview items and retrieve it using `getTag()` method.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 `When you click on the item you get its position` but the ListView position is not the same as the database id...

Comment: @DerGolem  You are correct,

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I want to set ids from db to a particlular list item, so that I can use it on onclick

Comment: You can use set tag. Or you can get the item at the clicked position and get the id which is same as database.

Comment: I would go with Rohit5k2 advice of using the ListItem setTag option. It's a clean and simple solution for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use SimpleAdapter, you provide it with an ArrayList of Maps.
What you should do is include your personid as an entry in your Map,  you don't have to bind it to any display element in your row, so it does not have to be displayed.

For example if your map is called rowMap, and the id is called personId

```
rowMap.put("person_id", personId);
adapterList.add(rowMap);
```

Then when your item is selected, you retrieve the Map using the position that is passed to your listener.  Once you have that, just call

```
map = adapterList.get(pos);
selectedId = map.get("person_id");
```

### Updated with a little more info on the SimpleAdapter

Here is a little more info on the SimpleAdapter, below is the doc on the constructor for reference.

The idea is that you create an ArrayList of Maps, each map entry has to have **at least** the data you want to display, but it can contain **more**
 data than what you want to display.

The `from` , `to` arrays that you provide adapt the map entry that you provide to the view that you provide.  If you include extra info in the map entry it is simply ignored and not displayed.  So in this case, assuming you don't want to display the personid, you would add personid to the Map entry, but not add it to the `from` , and `to` arrays

> public SimpleAdapter (Context context, List>
>   data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
>
> Added in API level 1 Constructor
>
> Parameters
>
> context: The context where the View associated with this
>   SimpleAdapter is running
>
> data: A List of Maps. Each entry in the List
>   corresponds to one row in the list. The Maps contain the data for each
>   row, and should include all the entries specified in "from"
>
> resource: Resource identifier of a view layout that defines the views
>   for this list item. The layout file should include at least those
>   named views defined in "to"
>
> from: A list of column names that will be
>   added to the Map associated with each item.
>
> to: The views that should
>   display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be TextViews.
>   The first N views in this list are given the values of the first N
>   columns in the from parameter.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply, one more thing, do I need to add this in the from and to arrays which  we use for initializing SimpleAdapter

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by add to the arrays, your SimpleAdapter just gets and ArrayList of Maps, right?  so that should not have to change, you just need to add and entry to the map.  I am also not sure what you mean by from and to arrays.  You should have one ArrayList that the adapter "adapts" to the ListView and the position you get back should be the index into that ArrayList

Comment: This is what i mean
       ' String[] from = { "flag", "txt", "cur", "vd", "gd",
    "ra" };

 
  int[] to = { R.id.flag, R.id.name, R.id.specialization,
    R.id.vd, R.id.gd, R.id.ra};

  
  adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,
    R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);'

Comment: Do I need to add the person Id in the from and to arrays

Comment: Sorry,  no you would not add personid to the from, to lists, __unless__ you wanted to display that in your row,  which I don't think you do.

Comment: The from array  represents the Keys used in Hashmap and the to  array represents the  Ids of views in layout, my question was , do I need to addthe Id using in hashmap ,  in this arrays

Comment: How can I do the same for a custom adapter , bcoz I have to changed  my sdapter to a custom adapter

Comment: The idea is the same.  An "adapter" basically takes what you have and adapts it to what is expected.  For this particular situation, you are expected to provide a way to "adapt" the data you have to what the list view is expecting,  so again , you just need to provide a way to map what you have to what you want to display.  It's perfectly fine to have additional data in your source data, you just need to provide a way to convert what you have to what you want to display.   Feel free to ask another question that is more specific to the problem you are having, and any thing you have tried.

Comment: thank you dude, I have made a way for this.  I have overriddedn getview and getitems in my custom adapter. Thank you for the response. Will post the code in the next comment

Comment: **This is the code to get the item details**

' ListView listView=(ListView)parent; '
     ' dataListAdapter adapter=(dataListAdapter)  '
' listView.getAdapter(); '

     
     ' HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(position); '
     
    
     ' Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "view details clicked  Id  "+item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
       .show(); '