# onClickListener for buttons inside the onItemClickListener of listview not working before item click

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` in android that displays person information from Database.
The `listview` is given an `OnItemClickListener()`  .  Inside the OnItemClickListener() I have also added few `onClickListener()` for the buttons  in the listview item.  On running the application , the buttons in the listview are not clickable or the `OnClickListener()` assigned for the buttons are not getting fired. **This issue will no longer appear , once the item in the listview is clicked.All the button click listeners are working after that.**
                        Can somebody give me a solution for this.The code I am using is the follows.

```
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            int listrowposition = arg2;
            HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) arg0
                    .getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
            final String id = item.get("ID");
            Button vd = (Button) arg1.findViewById(R.id.viewDetails);
            // this onclick listener is not working bfore the onitemclick
            // listener
            vd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "view details clicked  Id  " + id,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            Button gd = (Button) arg1.findViewById(R.id.getDirections);
            // this onclick listener is not working bfore the onitemclick
            // listener
            gd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "getDirections clicked  Id  " + id,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            Button ra = (Button) arg1.findViewById(R.id.reqAppointment);
            // this onclick listener is not working bfore the onitemclick
            // listener
            ra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "reqAppointment clicked  Id  " + id,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

The adapter i am using Is a SimpleAdapter .The adapter details are the follows.

```
       String[] from = { "flag", "txt", "cur", "viewDet", "getDirect",
            "reqAppnmnt" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag, R.id.name, R.id.specialization,
            R.id.viewDetails, R.id.getDirections, R.id.reqAppointment };

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,
            R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
    new CallToServer(adapter, aList).execute("");
    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
```

Comment: Add your adapter code and its better to writing inside adapter code so it will work

Comment: @AndoMasahashi I have edited the question with the adapter details

Comment: Create a custom adapter.

Comment: @Rohit5k2   Why is that required.  and   how the buttonclick is related with this.

Comment: Because your listener is assigned to the button only when you click on the listview item. If you want to be active all the time you need to make a custom adapter.

Comment: @dileepVikram: if you want to use Button in ListView rows then you also need to do something on click of Button for which you will need to add on click listener to Button. because `SimpleAdapter` is default implementation so you will need create a class to extends `SimpleAdapter`  class to modify `getView` method for adding listener to Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all create a custom adapter. This might help you [Custom Adapter for List View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Then add these methods in your adapter

```
private OnClickListener vdClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
        Log.v(TAG, "vd clicked, row %d", position);
    }
};

private OnClickListener gdClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
        Log.v(TAG, "gd clicked, row %d", position);
    }
};

private OnClickListener ravClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
        Log.v(TAG, "ra clicked, row %d", position);
    }
};
```

`mListView` is the listview you are using.

In your adapter `getView` method do something like this

```
Button vd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewDetails);
Button gd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.getDirections);
Button ra = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reqAppointment);
vd.setOnClickListener(vdClickListener);
gd.setOnClickListener(gdClickListener);
ra.setOnClickListener(raClickListener);
```

**EDIT**

A general code to make custom simple adapter is. You need to make changes in `getVeiw()` method.

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public Adapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data,
        int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistlayout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView rw1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.row1);
        rw1.setText("my text");
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail about developing a listview with list items include 2 text views and buttons ,  using custom adapter . I still didn't get a clear idea on how to implement custom adapters

Comment: How are you creating `aList`?

Comment: I am using a SimpleAdapter now, initially I just set a blank list to adapter. Then items are added to it later and . notifyDataSetChanged() is called .

Comment: I have edited my answer. You need to load the views as per your data and add listeners.

Comment: I am getting nullpointerexception at line   ra.setOnClickListener(ravClickListener);
What is the use of the following code
'View row = convertView;
   if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = mInflater
      .inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, parent, false);
   }'

Comment: did you do something like this `Button ra = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.ra)`?

Comment: yes, I have done few of such lines
'Button vd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewDetails);
   Button gd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.getDirections);
   Button ra = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reqAppointment);'

Comment: value of convertView   is null for me , why is that ?  And what is the use of the code
'View row = convertView;
   if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = mInflater
      .inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, parent, false);
   }'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70261/discussion-between-dileepvikram-and-rohit5k2).

Comment: Don't do it like `Button vd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewDetails);` do it this way `Button vd = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.viewDetails);` Change `convertView` to `row`

Comment: actually that nullpointerexception disappeared when used the view from the layoutinflater . But still the old issue persist there, like I am not able to click a button in the listitem, before clicking the listitem, can you please help , I mean the button click listener is working after the item click listener only.

Comment: You need to set click listener to all  the buttons in `getView` method and remove all the listeners from `onItemClick` (where you were using earlier)

Comment: I have seen ur  answer for my this question[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265181/setting-unique-id-to-listview-android?noredirect=1#comment44889392_28265181), can u comment on that on how I can do it for a custom adapter, when I posted that question , I was using a simpleadapter, Thanks a lot for ur quick responses :)

Answer (score 5):

Row xml must have this line ***android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"***

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    // All your widgets here

</LinearLayout>
```